# Non-linear system of ODE:s - Maximal existance interval.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

A modell for two competing species is the non-linear system of differentialequations

\begin{align}
y'_1(t) &= s_1 y_1(t)\left(1-\frac{y_1(t)}{N_1}\right)-a_1y_1(t)y_2(t)\\
y'_2(t) &= s_2 y_2(t)\left(1-\frac{y_2(t)}{N_2}\right)-a_2y_2(t)y_1(t)
\end{align}

where $s_i,N_i,a_i>0, \ i=1,2$ are positive parameters and $y_i(t)$ are the populationsizes of the respective species.

I want to show that the maximal existence interval for solutions to the system above with $t=0, \ y_1(0)>0, \ y_2(0)>0$ is the positive real numbers.

I don't know how to attack this problem since all the examples in my book only deal with single ODE:s where the initial value is given, like

$$y'(t)=y(t)^2, \quad y(0)=1,$$

where they simply solve this by separating variables. But how should I apply this to a system of non linear ODEs that has no analytical solution?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the trajectory stays in the region $0 < y_i \le \max(N_i, y_i(0))$.

Comment: Yes, I've concluded that aswell and I also drew a phase portrait (including the trajectories) but I can't see why this implies that the maximal existence intreval is R+.

Comment: The techniques used in the Picard–Lindelöf local existence and uniqueness theorem give you an estimate for $\delta$ such that the solution for initial condition $Y(t_0) = Y_0$ 
exists for $|t - t_0| < \delta$.  This $\delta$ is uniform if $Y_0$ is in a compact set.  If the interval stopped at some $T>0$, take the initial condition at some $t_0$ in $(T-\delta, T)$ and you see that it must continue past $T$.

Comment: Thank you Robert. However, I assume that your capital $Y(t)$ denotes $[y_1(t) \ \ y_2(t)]^T$ if I'm not mistaken. But how should I express the RHS in vector notation? In order to use the Picard-Lindelöf techniques as you suggest I need to show that $f(t,Y)$ and $\partial f/\partial Y$ are continous near $(t_0,Y_0).$