# Writing system of equations in matrix form.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How do I write this system of nonlinear ODE's in vector/matrix form?

\begin{align}
y'_1(t) &= s_1 y_1(t)\left(1-\frac{y_1(t)}{n_1}\right)-a_1y_1(t)y_2(t)\\
y'_2(t) &= s_2 y_2(t)\left(1-\frac{y_2(t)}{n_2}\right)-a_2y_2(t)y_1(t)
\end{align}

I want to rewrite this as something like

$$Y'=SY\left(1-\frac{Y}{N}\right)-A??$$

where all the capital letters are matrices/vectors. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it's not very satisfying.

Let $S = diag(s_1,s_2)$, $Y = diag(y_1,y_2)$, $N = diag(\frac{1}{n_1},\frac{1}{n_2})$, $\gamma = diag(a_1,a_2)$, and finally let $P$ be the permutation matrix such that $Y_P = PY = diag(y_2,y_1)$.

Then your system is:

$$\vec{y}' = SY\bigg(1-NY\bigg)-\gamma Y P Y$$

Comment: Yeah, it was of no use for me. Darn! Well I thank you for this and here is my upvote. However, this stems from another problem I posted yesterday: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3182708/non-linear-system-of-odes-maximal-existance-interval/3182722?noredirect=1#comment6550660_3182722 Maybe ODE's is not your expertise but I'd appreciate it if you had some input on how to go about it. Essentially I want to compute $\partial f/\partial Y$ for the system as a whole, if thats necessary.

Comment: Sadly I'm afraid you're right - I'm not sure how to answer the linked question, sorry!

Comment: No worries mate! At least now I can cross this matrix idea from my list of possible solutions.